# what is the use of salt specifically the word "perturb"

Tags: unix, encryption, cryptography

While developing a brute force based cracking algorithm for unix password I met with this line:       "salt is a two-character string chosen from the set [a-zA-Z0-9./].  This string is used  to  perturb  the algorithm in one of 4096 different ways."

I did not get 4096 ways?? 2^12 but how??

Comment: _perturb_ 1. To disturb greatly; make uneasy or anxious.
2. To throw into great confusion. [source](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/perturb)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: User 1 picks password "secret".  User 2 picks password "secret".  Both passwords will hash to the same value, so cracking one also cracks the other.  Now add salt.  User1 now has password "secretZ3".  User2 now has password "secretjY".  They hash to different values, so cracking one does not reveal the other password.  The salt "perturbs" the resulting hash value so matching passwords do not have matching hashes.

Answer (score 4):

The set [a-zA-Z0-9./] is made up of 64 characters. Selecting two characters each from the full 64 character set gives 64 * 64 possibilities, or 4096.

Comment: But while using the crypt function as defined under unistd.h library it asks for salt. So computer automatically chooses one among the 4096 possibilities??

Comment: @user2035503 That's what the excerpt you quoted says.